# cakephp bake new page from panel admin

Tags: php, cakephp

Let say i've got simple index page baked in cakephp.
 There is also admin panel to administrate it. I've heard about some functionality  to create from admin panel a totally new wepage automatically  (CRUD wepages in cake), but I can't find any example.

I would like to make a function to create from admin panel a totally new wepage automatically.

For example add page with a name "contact" and write there my data. All of it ofcourse online.
How to manage it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a big question to write it all down, but..  Try getting started with something like this.

You could make a simple form that add pages in the database. With a Page title and Page content.

For the content i suggest you use some kind of editor like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). 
So you can style your page a little bit (online) and add code in de editor (online, without changing the code in a code editor(offline))

For the navbar, you can use in the controller `$this->set('pages', $this->Webpage->find('All'));`

So you can get them trough a foreach. Like here:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($pages as $page)
{
   echo '<a href="/'.$page['Webpage']['title'].'"><li>'.$page['Webpage']['title'].'</li></a>';
}
</ul>
```

Once they click on a link, they go to `www.mywebsite.com/contact`. You can get the information from that page via `$this->params->url;` To put it in your query.

```
$this->Webpage->findByName($this->params->url);
```